# plug in scrolling users, much like facebook, not slider that i now

Tags: plugins

I would like to make a scrolling system to scroll the users of my forum when you click on the small arrow to the left or right of the system.

Here is what I want:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TZj5y.png)
I hope this will help you understand me.
Thank you I ask for your help.

Comment: Please be more specific. What kind of plugin are you talking about, what is the platform/system where you need the plugin? Also, what is your question?

Comment: Your question is not entirely clear. What platform do you work on? can you graph the operation using mspaint or search for an image on the internet?

Comment: I just found a capture I was looking for on facebook since yesterday; I hope it helps you understand me.

[enter image description here][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/qX5Ma.png